Can $1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, \dots$ be called a geometric sequence?
The sequence $1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, \dots$ seems to satisfy a geometric sequence.
But it is an oscillating function.
I thought a geometric function should be monotonically increasing or decreasing or a constant. Am I mistaken?

A geometric series is one for which the ratio of successive terms is constant,  and this qualifies.  If you want to include $0$ then you'd define as a sequence of the form $a_n= Ar^n$ for constants $A,r$.

Its a geometric sequence. $a_n=(-1)^n$.  $b_n=(-1)^{n-1}/2^n. \sum b_n =1$

It sounds like so far you've only seen geometric sequences where the common ratio is nonnegative; in that case the sequence is monotonic. But geometric sequences can have negative common ratio as well, and (as we see here) such sequences are not monotonic. (It's a good exercise to prove these statements!)

Yes. A geometric sequence is any sequence that takes the form $\{ar^n\}$. In this case, $a = r = -1$, but it's still perfectly valid.

A sequence of terms $\{t_n\}$ is geometric if $\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=\frac{t_n}{t_{n-1}}$.
Such a ratio is often denoted $r$.
In this case $r=-1$ so the sequence meets the requirement for a geometric sequence/progression.
